# How to use LINQ in SQL Server and C#?

Tags: asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to use LINQ in ASP.NET to make the performance fast with the quick access to SQL Server 2008.
I want to know how to use the Linq queue in C#. So I can perform all Linq query in my project.

Comment: If your only intention for using LINQ is *to make the performance fast*, then your question might be pointless. Anyway, the question as it stands is not constructive and is likely to be closed..

Answer (score 1):

This page is your friend, study it :)

101 examples of linq used in simple, yet extensive ways, should be no problem expanding on this

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Good answer for a badly structured Question I suppose